# CURL Isn't Working with MyBB and Flask

Tags: php, flask, mybb

I'm trying to send POST with JSON to an external Flask server from my MyBB Forum with CURL. The code works outside of MyBB (I tested it on REPL), but I couldn't make it work in MyBB. CURL is enabled on the server and I can send PHP to PHP without any problem. Thanks in advance.

```php
function send($class, $method) {
    $dict = $this->dict; // an array
    $dict["sender"] = "panel";
    $json = json_encode($dict);
    $ch = curl_init("http://blabla/operation/" . $class . "/" . $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
    );
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Here is the full code: https://hastebin.com/mecubapenu.php

Edit:

As a note, I can't see the request on Flask. It seems like it's not sending it.

Comment: Are both apps running on the same host or even in the same networked infrastructure? Sometimes servers aren't able to resolve an internal connection via the external name; you may need to find the internal hostname to use

Comment: No, they have no relation. While the MyBB and PHP are on a shared hosting from GoDaddy, Flask is on my VPS from a reseller which buys it as dedicated server from Hetzner.

I can reach "http://myip/test.php" but I cannot reach "http://myip:5000/operation/Login/verify", I can give this as an example. And as I said, I can reach "http://myip:5000/operation/Login/verify" from repl.it without changing my code. It's like seeing a flying sheep, I can't explain why it happens and its not logical to happen.